# При изменении массива созданного методом .filter() изменяется исходный массив

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

помогите пожалуйста разобраться.

Моя задача, на основании двух массивов создать новый массив с некоторой комбинацией данных.  (Google Apps Script)

Используемый код:

```
function newArrayToFilter() {

  //Исходные массивы данных
  const dataArray1 = [[1, 2, "Str"], [3, 3, "Str"], [2, 2, "Str"], [4, 3, "Str"]];//Исходный массив 1
  const dataArray2 = [[2, 5], [2, 8], [3, 4], [3, 2]];//Исходный массив 2

  //Создаем массив результатов
  let arrResult = new Array();

  //Создаем массив отфильтрованных элементов
  let arrValueFilter = new Array;


  //Запускаем цикл по массиву 1
  for (row of dataArray1) {
    arrValueFilter = dataArray2.filter(item => item[0] === row[1]);//Фильтруем данные из массива 2 по элементу из массива 1

  //Запускаем цикл по отфильтрованным данных
    for (row2 of arrValueFilter) {//Обходим массив полученных результатов и изменяем данные
      row2.push(row[2]) //Добавляем элемент в массив
    }

  //Записываем модифицированные данные в массив результатов
    arrResult = arrResult.concat(arrValueFilter);
  }
}
```

На выходе нужен массив вида:

```
[[2.0, 5.0, Str], [2.0, 8.0, Str], [3.0, 4.0, Str], [3.0, 2.0, Str], [2.0, 5.0, Str], [2.0, 8.0, Str], [3.0, 4.0, Str], [3.0, 2.0, Str]]
```

Это код генерирует такой результат:

```
[[2.0, 5.0, Str, Str], [2.0, 8.0, Str, Str], [3.0, 4.0, Str, Str], [3.0, 2.0, Str, Str], [2.0, 5.0, Str, new_Value], [2.0, 8.0, Str, Str], [3.0, 4.0, Str, Str], [3.0, 2.0, Str, Str]]
```

На сколько я понимаю, причина в том, что изменяется массив dataArray2 и при следующих итерациях цикла над массивом dataArray1 приходят измененные данные массива dataArray2.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По своей сути функция .filter() должна создавать новый массив, но судя по всему у меня ссылается на тот же массив.

Подскажите, что я делаю не так?

Comment: меняется не массив, а **элемент**. Элемент, в отличие от массива остается тот же самый, поэтому его изменения будут видны везде

Comment: Если ты не хочешь чтобы менялся исходный массив - копируй его

Comment: @Grundy спасибо за ответ. Получается, что используя метод filter() создается новый массив, который ссылается на элементы исходного массива?

Comment: именно это и происходит

Comment: @Grundy теперь понятно, спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял твою логику действий - то код ниже. Я просто проверил, чтобы результат совпадал с тем, что ты хочешь. Лучше бы кроме кода объяснять и смысл, логику. Хотя, может просто именно мне это было неявно)

```
function newArrayToFilter2() {
  //Исходные массивы данных
  const dataArray1 = [[1, 2, "Str"], [3, 3, "Str"], [2, 2, "Str"], [4, 3, "Str"]];//Исходный массив 1
  const dataArray2 = [[2, 5], [2, 8], [3, 4], [3, 2]];//Исходный массив 2

  //Создаем массив результатов
  let arrResult = [];

  dataArray1
    .forEach(row => {
      //Фильтруем данные из массива 2 по элементу из массива 1
      let arrValueFilter = dataArray2
        .filter(item => item[0] === row[1])
        .map(item => item.concat(row[2]));

      //Записываем модифицированные данные в массив результатов
      arrResult = arrResult.concat(arrValueFilter);
  });

  console.info(arrResult);
}
```

Вывод:

```
[[ 2, 5, 'Str' ], [ 2, 8, 'Str' ], [ 3, 4, 'Str' ], [ 3, 2, 'Str' ], [ 2, 5, 'Str' ], [ 2, 8, 'Str' ], [ 3, 4, 'Str' ], [ 3, 2, 'Str' ]]
```

Comment: Благодарю! Подход работает на реальных данных)
Данные в вопросе слишком абстрактные создал, видимо поэтому не понятно)

Задача следующая - создать спецификации для производимых товаров по шаблону.

Есть таблица производимых товаров (массив [dataArray1 ]  в примере.

Есть таблица шаблонов спецификаций продукции (массив [dataArray2] в примере). (Из чего состоит продукция).

Для каждого товара (запись из [dataArray1 ] требуется получить "Шаблонный состав" из [dataArray2].

На следующих этапах (в примере отсутствуют) спецификация каждого товара модифицируется и получается уник. изделие.

Answer (score 0):

Как-то вот так, наверное есть более логический способ. Но конец рабочего дня и голова не варит)

P.S: там у тебя 2 цикл запускается внутри первого цикла, заметил ты это или нет, но думаю это ошибка

```js
function newArrayToFilter() {

    const dataArray1 = [[1, 2, "Str"], [3, 3, "Str"], [2, 2, "Str"], [4, 3, "Str"]];
    const dataArray2 = [[2, 5], [2, 8], [3, 4], [3, 2]];

    let arrResult = new Array();

    let arrValueFilter = new Array;

    for (row of dataArray1) {
      arrValueFilter = dataArray2.filter(item => item[0] === row[1]);
      arrResult = arrResult.concat(arrValueFilter);
    }
    for (row2 of arrResult) {
      row2[2] = 'new_Value';
    }
  }
  newArrayToFilter();
```

Comment: Прошу не судить строго, я чисто любитель

Comment: Спасибо за внимание к вопросу и код, циклы вложенные умышленно, т.к. вместо "new_Value" используется значение из 1 цикла, например row[0]. Поэтому они и вложенные... Извиняюсь, сейчас поправлю вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

### Вариант 1

```js
function newArrayToFilter1() {
  // Исходные массивы данных
  const dataArray1 = [
    [1, 2, 'Str'],
    [3, 3, 'Str'],
    [2, 2, 'Str'],
    [4, 3, 'Str'],
  ]; // Исходный массив 1
  const dataArray2 = [
    [2, 5],
    [2, 8],
    [3, 4],
    [3, 2],
  ]; // Исходный массив 2

  const arrResult = dataArray1.reduce(
    (acc, row) => (
      acc.res.push(...acc.data.filter((item) => item[0] === row[1]).map((item) => item.concat(row[2]))), acc
    ),
    { res: [], data: dataArray2 }
  );

  console.info(arrResult.res);
}
```

### Вариант 2

```js
function newArrayToFilter1() {
  // Исходные массивы данных
  const dataArray1 = [
    [1, 2, 'Str'],
    [3, 3, 'Str'],
    [2, 2, 'Str'],
    [4, 3, 'Str'],
  ]; // Исходный массив 1
  const dataArray2 = [
    [2, 5],
    [2, 8],
    [3, 4],
    [3, 2],
  ]; // Исходный массив 2

  const arrResult = dataArray1.reduce(reducer_, { res: [], data: dataArray2 });

  console.info(arrResult.res);
}

function reducer_(acc, row) {
  acc.res.push(...acc.data.filter((item) => item[0] === row[1]).map((item) => item.concat(row[2])));
  return acc;
}
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответы! Весьма лаконичное решение) Пойду изучать метод .reduce(). Спасибо!